# Prestashop webservice, request random row of ressources

Tags: php, api, prestashop

I'm developping a webservice on prestashop using the PSWebServiceLibrary with php.
That i want is to make request that get random row , for example i want to get 10 random products.
On the webservice api there is no option which can make this one; Is there a way to make that request using the PSWebServiceLibrary on php? Like i made below:

```
 public function get_random_product(){
        $webservice = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
        $opt['resource'] = 'products';
        $opt['filter']['active'] = 1;
        $opt['limit'] = 10;
        $opt['display'] = 'full';
        $xmlResponse = $webservice->get($opt);
        $allproducts = $xmlResponse->children()->children();
        return ($allproducts);
 }
```

This one just get the 10 first row product but i want that the result is random. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get 10 random products from DB with this

```
select id_product from ps_product order by rand() limit 10;
```

And then retrieve from API with, for example

```
www.yourapp.com/api/products/?filter[id]=[1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10]
```

In your function

```
public function get_random_product(){
    $rows = DB::getInstance()->executeS('select id_product from ps_product where active order by rand() limit 10');
    $joinedIdProducts = implode('|', $rows);
    $webservice = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
    $opt['resource'] = 'products';
    $opt['filter']['active'] = 1;
    $opt['filter']['id'] = $joinedIdProducts;
    $opt['limit'] = 10;
    $opt['display'] = 'full';
    $xmlResponse = $webservice->get($opt);
    $allproducts = $xmlResponse->children()->children();
    return ($allproducts);
```

}

Comment: Hi :) sorry i was not realy clear about my question, i've rectified it, i want to use the library php provided by prestashop, and using it to get the random result :)

Comment: Add $opt['filter']['id'] = $joinedIdProducts;

Comment: The problem is that i don't have the product id, i can't just make a random number to put in the filter
And making another request to just retrieve the id take more ressource i think,

Comment: Of course, you need id from DB. Watch updated answer.

Comment: it's helpful but isn't there another way to make it in one request? without making the first request?
Cause as i already said, it take more ressource than one request :)

Comment: As you can see in https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/tutorials/advanced-use/additional-list-parameters/ there is not such functionality. On the other hand, due Prestashop modularity this case is not the worst about performance you are going to meet in Prestashop.